# Rspec failing expect errors_on. Expected 1, got 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

So I have a factory

```
factory :comment do
    sequence :text do |n|
        "I like this#{n}"
    end
    association :post
end
```

And I have an expectation in rspec showing this.

```
  it "does not allow duplicate comments on one post" do
    post = build(:post)
    comment1 = create(:comment, post: post)
    comment2 = build(:comment, post: post)
    expect(:comment2).to have(1).errors_on(:text)
end
```

However it keeps failing saying:

```
1) Comment does not allow duplicate comments on one post
 Failure/Error: expect(:comment2).to have(1).errors_on(:text)
   expected 1 errors on :text, got 8
 # ./spec/models/comment_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I can't seem to figure out why it has 8 errors and what they would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your spec - comment2 is a variable, not a symbol, so it should be `expect(comment2).to have(1).errors_on(:text)`.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  It is always the simplest things that get me.  I was putting a expect(build(:comment)) in another spec and it threw me off.  Thank you!!